# Execute trap while using read

Tags: input, sh, posix

I have a script where I accept input using `read`, but I also want to detect `WINCH` and do something when the terminal resizes.

However, I have noticed that nothing happens until after the `read` is done (that is, pressing <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd>).

Is there some way to react to the `WINCH` while reading? Or perhaps what I need is a different method of reading the text?

Comment: When the terminal resizes, do you want to end `read` early, or just suspend it and resume it after the "something" is done?

Comment: I want to keep `read` after detecting the resize.